# azure sql database bcp freezes and rolls back

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am BCPing a 130GB text file into Azure SQL Database. In the last 800 records the BCP stalls. I left it for 8 hours and the Azure database went from 150GB down to 30GB (rolled back), the table was empty, and DTU usage was stuck at 0. By mistake I left a clustered index on the table so I figured maybe this had something to do with the rollback. So I deleted the index and re-ran it and it uploaded much faster but it appears to be stalled again.

[image]

The database is currently at 157GB and was at 30GB before starting the BCP. 
[image]

What could be causing it to stall/roll back? Any logs or something I can check?

Comment: Consider specifying the `-b` parameter along with a batch size (e.g. 100000).

Comment: @DanGuzman The error came up transaction log is full due to 'Active_Transaction'. Good thing i'm paying over 9g a month for this database... do i need to wait for this to roll back the transaction or can i kill it and re-start? Will increasing batch size work or do I need to upload in smaller files? Can BCP in select chunks for me?

Comment: The entire file is bulk inserted as a single transaction by default. A smaller batch size spec like I suggested will avoid that without selecting in chunks. You'll need to let the transaction rollback.

Comment: @DanGuzman hey thanks for your help. I used a batch size of 100k like you said but because I was in a crunch for time I couldn't take any risks so I used the -F and -L commands to insert in chunks. It did work. Based on your suggestion and by the looks of it, your experience. I have not truly tested it and probably won't until I run into this issue again but I'm interested in understanding why 1K batch size will cause a full transaction log but a 100k wouldn't (with this current data set).

Comment: @MIME, are you saying you specified a `-b 1000` on your command? Without it, the 1000 rows sent messages are just progress messages and the actual batch size is the entire file.

Comment: @DanGuzman ahh, got it! yeah i think i may have not specified. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: glad to help. I expanded on my comments with answer to better help others with a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute the `BCP` without a batch size specified with the `-b` argument, the entire file is processed in a single transaction. The rows sent messages only indicate only progress in that case. BCPing a large file in a single transaction will require significant transaction log space and often reduces performance too due to the large number of dirty pages.

With the `-b` argument, the specified batch size controls the size of each transaction. Each batch is committed individually and the progress messages will reflect the batch size too.